# How to launch XAML page across the pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 application. My requirement is to create side menu control which is similar to facebook side menu. My application has 10 XAML pages. I want to use this side menu control in all of my pages. I don't want to copy paste the code in all the 10 pages. Instead i am preferring to create a global XAML page and use across the pages. If i click the side menu, it should open like facebook side menu in all of my 10 XAML pages. I am having the source code in which the control is used in only one page. But i want to use the control globally. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either extract side menu ability in a separate user control and then simply use that user control on every page or you can create a page that acts as a *frame* around user controls.

In the former case, you need to copy/paste a few lines of code on every page you have to add the side control. In the latter case you must do the following:
 - create a master page which contains a side control and has an empty space for the page's content
 - instead of writing pages, write user controls and load them inside the master page
 - when navigating, simply reload the content in the middle.

The latter case gives you full control, but you develop your applications differently.

Comment: And last (and least) you can fiddle with the actual Frame control which contains all your pages, e.g. by adjusting the Frame's template. This way you can keep the standard navigation code, but wiring the Frame's content can be tricky.

Comment: Could you send a sample to msa2603@yahoo.co.in please?